# Text Overlap in CSS

Tags: css

Just a quick question - I was unable to find this when I searched, but I'm sorry if it's a repeat.

I have paragraph tags enclosing the title of my website:

```
<div class = "title">
  <p>Welcome to homepage!</p>
</div>

<div class = "subtext"> 
  <p> Subtext goes here </p>
</div>

<div class = "formthing">
  <form method = "GET" action = "/form">
     <input type = "submit" name = "submitted" class = "btn-large" value = "Click button" />
  </form>
</div>
```

and everything is working fine. However, when I zoom in on the page, the words of the title overlap themselves. Is there anything I can add to CSS to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Please add quite a bit more info than that. No one can help with nothing to go off of.

Comment: how do you expect people to help you when there is no code provided. rovide  fiddle

Answer (score 0):

i dont see any overlap in your code, but a quick fix would be to can add margins to your classes via css to prevent overlaping.

eg:

```
<style>
.formthing {
 margin: 0.25em;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `em` font-sizing in your CSS.  If you don't know what this is, this is a really good article on it:  http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Essentially `em` is just another way of expressing a percentage but some browsers falter at higher and lower levels of zoom when using `pt`, `px` and `%` values.  Using `em` mitigates this issue the best.

```
font-size: 16px;
font-size: 100%;
font-size: 1em;
```

Most modern browsers will default to 16px font-size as the control and adjust off of that, making the above 3 font-sizes equal to each other (give or take some decimals in Firefox and IE).  This isn't fool-proof but for the most part will get you through these situations.  It's a very widely practiced and proven method of preventing unexpected text and element overlapping.

Also - might wanna look into the font you're using and whether there is any kerning applied and maybe utilize `letter-spacing: 1px;` and adjust accordingly.

Don't forget to use a CSS reset like **[Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)**.